# change opacity of image using imagick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

I want to change opacity of multiple images when i used [setImageOpacity](http://www.php.net//manual/en/imagick.setimageopacity.php) it work fine for all images but not with png images and when i used [evaluateImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.evaluateimage.php) it is work fine for transparent images but not for other images. how can i used same method for all types of images if image is transparent or not this is the code

```
<?php
// Open the original image
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage(3.jpg);

// Open the watermark
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage(2.png);

    $watermark->setImageOpacity(0.444);
    //$watermark->evaluateImage(Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, 0.0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);


$watermark->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel('transparent'), 90); 
// Overlay the watermark on the original image
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 20, 20);

// send the result to the browser
header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use if condition using [getImageAlphaChannel()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagealphachannel.php)  function

to detect if the image have any transparent

note :

> This method is available if Imagick has been compiled against
>   ImageMagick version 6.4.0 or newer.